# vsftp work in terminal but not on filezilla and browser

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, vsftpd, vsftp

I work under in a docker image, under a VPS!
i have install vsftp in my ubuntu 20.04! at the beginning I tested ftp 127.0.0.1 in the command line and everything goes well I created a user and I tested the file transfer.
after adding the ssl certificate and I wanted to connect by filezilla or by browser it does not work and the server does not have the ip address 127.0.0.1!
how can I fix this please!

here is the output of filezilla :

Response: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)

Command: AUTH TLS

Answer: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.

Command: AUTH SSL

Answer: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.

Status: Unsecured server, it does not support FTP over TLS.

Command: USER rayen

Answer: 530 Permission denied.

there is nothings in the file log => it's empty  /var/log/vsftpd.log

/etc/vsftpd.conf : listen=NO

listen_ipv6=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES

user_sub_token=$USER

local_root=/home/$USER/ftp

pasv_min_port=30000

pasv_max_port=31000

userlist_enable=YES

userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list

userlist_deny=NO

i followed this tuto :

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-vsftpd/

Comment: Show us a log from the terminal.  + Did you check the server-side log?

Comment: this is vsftp.log

Comment: Fri Apr  9 05:37:48 2021 [pid 1647] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:71.6.232.4"
Fri Apr  9 05:45:37 2021 [pid 1649] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:192.241.204.244"

Comment: Please do not post any information in comments. Edit everything into your question. + Try increase vsftpd logging level. + Post console log.

Comment: aaa ok sorry it's the first time that i posted here !

Answer (score -1):

> Status: Unsecured server, it does not support FTP over TLS.

You need to issue a certificate (I suggest using Let's Encrypt for this)
After issuing a certificate, set these variables on /etc/vsftpd.conf file

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server.key
ssl_enable=YES
```

To connect using Filezilla, remember to select the option **Use explicit FTP over TLS if available**.

Comment: listen=NO 
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
pasv_min_port=35000
pasv_max_port=40000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES  !!!! and always the  same problem !! i think that firezilla don't  see my server !!!!

Comment: @RayenBenSaid The error message says your "server doesn't support FTP over TLS", so you're supposed to not be using a valid certificate

Comment: I have this setup working fine and connection via FileZilla with FTP over TLS

Comment: it's normal that ftp:\\x.x.x.x don't work ??? i enter my user name and passwrd and nothings happen – Rayen Ben Said